# Wait for a method to return true

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have two methods A and B. A calls the B method from inside. B method returns true or false whether a file is having content or not. Here is the code:

```
    public static void A()
    {
        var isValid = B();
        // Wait until "isValid" comes true
        var xx = "test";
    }

    public static bool B()
    {
        // This will check for a file content
        // Say C://test.txt
        // If the file has some content this method will return true else false
    }
```

I want the A method to wait and do not execute the "var xx = "test";" line unless the B method returns true. Can you help me by giving some pointers how to do that?

EDIT: I cant use if loop simply i.e if(isValid) because the file for which the content is to be checked is written by some other thread so I need to continuously check that B method from inside the A. I can't let this piece of code "var xx = "test";" to be executed unless B returns true and if it is returning false the code should wait there (at var isValid = B();) unless B returns true i.e the code should continuously check the B status.

Comment: If your executing both methods on same thread, it will wait till B() finishes. Are you using multi-threading?

Comment: As an unrelated comment does your `B` method confirm that all the data is in the file rather than just some? Depending on how the file is generated you might need to make sure that you don't register the file as having contents while it is still being written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a while loop

```
while (!B ()) { }
var x = "test";
```

This will execute B until it returns true. A better approach is probably to implement an event which will trigger when a condition turns true.

Considering you're using files,  you could look into FileSystemWatcher,  which can trigger a method if a file changes.

Comment: Particularly +1 for suggesting events as a better option. Also if you need to have a comment to point out the empty statement you might be better off with `{}`.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `FileSystemWatcher` object with the `Changed` event handler pointed to a method that will be executed when the file content changes (and has content after the change).

See the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(B())
    var xx = "test";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static void A()
    {
       while(!B())
        {
       var isValid = B(); //whatever the code 
        }
     var xx = "test";
    }
```

Comment: Why do you call `B()` inside the loop?

Comment: calling to be executed

Comment: @MoatazAmer: the point is you call B every iteration of your while loop since it is the loop condition so you don't need to call it again in your loop unless you were looping on `isValid` instead of directly on `B()`. That might have better readability for some but at the moment you are doing a pointless method call in the loop body.

Comment: hmmm he seems that he want to use the returned value from B() ... after it become true ! ,so he may need to invoke it again after checking it became true

Answer (score -2):

If you need to use the value returned by the method, let's say a string that must be "cat".

Based on @moataz-amer 's answer, but optimized so you don't need to invoke the method twice on the loop:

```
public static void A()
{
   string mustBeCat = string.Empty;

   while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mustBeCat) || !mustBeCat.Contains("cat"))
    {
      mustBeCat = B(); //whatever the code
    }

 //mustBeCat == "cat" so the method can go on 
}
```